# Creating shortcuts on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I'd like to create a shortcut for `Terminator` on Ubuntu 16.04 through *System Settings > Keyboard > Custom Shortcuts*, however I don't know how to fill in *Command* field.

[image: New shortcuts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you have in your question is for creating **Keyboard** shortcuts.  Not just shortcuts.

The fields you see in your image are for a description and the actual command for calling your application.

The actual **Keyboard** shortcut comes from the key you specify for your command.

As wjandrea has said, you put a name (which is a friendly name for calling your Keyboard Shortcut) in the first field.  The second field is the actual command to run your application.

The part that you are missing is the **Keyboard Shortcut**.  This is the **Key stroke** that you will be hitting to activate the command.  This is set after you create the command... after you have filled the information in the fields of your image.

**Fill in the information such as:**

```
Name:    Terminator
Command: /usr/bin/terminator
```

Then click **Apply**

**Now add the actual keyboard shortcut**

Now the step that you are missing is called **Activate** your new shortcut by applying a key.  If you want your **Keyboard Shortcut** to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> you will assign this **keyboard shortcut scroke** by clicking the mouse on the word **disabled**  that is associated by default with your new entry.  Then hit the keystroke you want to activate your command.  In the case of the example I'm explaning, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  The **keyboard stroke** you hit will from then on (unless you disable it) will launch your application.

You can disable it by clicking on the entry and hitting the **backspace** for the entry.

**Note:**

The GUI program refers to this assignment as a **New accelerator**.

Answer (score 1):

In the "command" field, put `terminator`, the name of the executable file that invokes the *Terminator* application.

Alternatively you can specify the full path to the executable:

```
/usr/bin/terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put `/usr/bin/terminator` or the path to it because if you were to put that in the command line, it would launch it.